# Question on Nilpotent Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let us suppose $S$ to be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and to possess a  dimension of 4. Let us presume, in addition, $X$ to be a $4 \times 4$ matrix such that $(X^2 - 2X + 2I)^4 =0$. (Clearly, then, $X^2-2X+2I$ is  a nilpotent matrix). I wish to know whether it is true that $(X^2-2X+2I)^2 =0$.

Comment: Why is it clear that $X$ is nilpotent? In fact, it seems clear to me that $X$ *cannot* be nilpotent

Comment: $X$ is not nilpotent at all.

Comment: If $X$ has real entries, then it is true that 
$$
(X^2 - 2X + 2I)^4 =0 \implies (X^2 - 2X + 2I)^2 =0.
$$
However, this does not hold for arbitrary complex matrices.

Comment: Ah, I had made a mistake when typing. I had rather meant that $X^2-2X+2I$ was nilpotent.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $z^2-2z+2 = 0$. Consider the matrix
$$X =\begin{pmatrix} z & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 &z &1 & 1 \\0 & 0 & z & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & z \end{pmatrix}$$

Then you have
$$X^2-2X+2I = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 &0 &-1 & -1 \\0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

It is clear that $(X^2-2X+2I)^4 = 0$, but $(X^2-2X+2I)^2 \neq 0$.

Comment: How did you find this counter example?

Comment: We want the matrix $X^2-2X+2I$ to be nilpotent of order $4$ but not $2$ : the simplest example is a triangular one, with $0$ on the diagonal, but non-zero coefficients just above the diagonal. So we have to find $X$ such that $X^2-2X+2I$ has this form. Taking for $X$ a triangular matrix is the simplest way to be sure that $X^2-2X+2I$ is triangular, and putting this $z$ on the diagonal to ensure that the diagonal elements of $X^2-2X+2I$ will be zero. For the other elements, I tried randomly, because there was a very small chance to get a nilpotent matrix of order $2$.